# I'm programming an Android application. I want to use XPath to parse XML

Tags: java, import, project

How do I include this in my Android package? 
When I do:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
```

It simply doesn't work?  Do I have to put files into my JAVA project? Where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath expressions are not part of Android (yet). There have been several solutions, for example look at this [blog](http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/05/19/the-force-unleashed-xmlxpath-on-android-using-dom4j-and-jaxen/). Haven't tested this myself yet.

Comment: xPath is a part of Android since 2.2 ; check http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html

Comment: @AnkitJain is right. It is now part of android. Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/2816899/155813