# I want to use Xpath in Android to parse XML

Tags: xml, android, parsing, xpath

I like to use Xpath to parse XML ins java, but when I am doing the same on android, XPath is not found.

any idea how it can be implemented. and also if its not possible then any other parser for android which is fast?

Thanks

Kai

Comment: XPath address part of XML tree instance that might be the result of **parsing an XML document** or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Android XPath is available (i.e. as a ready-to-use implementation) since Android API Level 8 (I think thats Android 2.2) you can find more information [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html).

To get you started - within the scope of an activity try:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "myNode";
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(expression, parser, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

The "parser" can be obtained by putting ur xml document into your res/xml folder (you might have to create that xml folder yourself). Then you can access it via:

```
//Do this withon the scope of an activity, you need the activitie's context!
Resources res = getResources();
//Get the xml file
//this is how you access the content of the xml folder 
//you previously created in the res folder
parser = res.getXml(R.xml.yourxmlfile);
```

Comment: I have an error with this :
javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Unknown error in XPath.

My XML :

<keywords>
    <keyword>
        <word>book</word>
        <definition>azerty</definition>
    </keyword>
    <keyword>
        <word>cat</word>
        <definition>qwerty</definition>
    </keyword>
    <keyword>
        <word>house</word>
        <definition>qsdfghjkl</definition>
    </keyword>
</keywords>

Comment: @Ready4Android what if an XML is stored on the server and you're accessing it via URL? How do I pass that URL to res.getXML(); ?

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me. Perhaps the Android XPath api has changed since 2011? Using `parser = res.getXml(R.xml.yourxmlfile)` trigger the following exception in the call to `xpath.evaluate`:  "javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'org.apache.xml.dtm.DTMAxisTraverser org.apache.xml.dtm.DTM.getAxisTraverser(int)' on a null object reference". Obtaining `parser` this way result in an object of type XmlResourceParser. The xpath.evaluate function expects an InputSource though, and this triggers the exception.