# SelectNodes in Android?

Tags: android, xpath, selectnodes

Is the method `.selectNodes` available in Android ?
I need to access particular data in a xhtml code using its XPath.

I read the method exists in Android since API Level 8, but I don't know how to use it and what packages to import in my code.

PS: I am used to use `getElementsByTagName`, but it isn't as powerful as `SelectNodes`.

```
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("title");
```

Comment: you can look at similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816899/i-want-to-use-xpath-in-android-to-parse-xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`XPath` package](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) is indeed supported since API Level 8. If you're wondering how to use that, simply specify your build target to be at least this level (Android 2.2 and above).

However, the core functionality for parsing HTML/XML documents, that has been around since API Level 1, is provided by [`Document`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Document.html). Although this class contains the `getElementsByTagName` method, `selectNodes` appears to be missing. In stead you could use an external libary like dom4j, which does provide [`selectNodes(String xpathExpression)`](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/dom4j/Node.html#selectNodes%28java.lang.String%29) to evaluate an XPath expression. Just add the dom4j jar to your build path and you should be good to go.

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you so much :D I was asking about the second part ! Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad to be of help. :) If you find an answer satisfies your question, please mark it as solved.