# Parsing XMl in Android using Xpath

Tags: android, xml, parsing, xpath

I want to parse an xml file using xpath in android, any idea how to do that??

I hope you get the point. Thank you ;)

Comment: I got your point but for the correctness, we can't "parse an XML file using XPath" but to use an XML parser to do that. And yet, we can only extract nodes' data using XPath :)

Comment: XPath is a hosted language. So, what language is going to host your XPath expression?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I'm programming an Android application. I want to use XPath to parse XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250603/im-programming-an-android-application-i-want-to-use-xpath-to-parse-xml)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the samples given in this post

http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/05/19/the-force-unleashed-xmlxpath-on-android-using-dom4j-and-jaxen/

Answer (score 1):

It seems that as of 2.2 it's now part of the language, so no need for the other external libs...
http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

This looks to have been asked and answered before [I'm programming an Android application. I want to use XPath to parse XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250603/im-programming-an-android-application-i-want-to-use-xpath-to-parse-xml). Hopefully that link to the blog post helps.